# Whats the difference between writing MethodChannel bridge versus dart:ffi bridge to run c/c++ code to get the response?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, dart-ffi, flutter-method-channel

Before I start my question I want to point out that it's not similar this question.
[Difference between writing platform specific code vs dart:ffi code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899563/difference-between-writing-platform-specific-code-vs-dartffi-code). Here the questioner is asking the actual difference whereas I am trying to know the difference for the same task that can be achieved using both methods.

What's the difference in running native c/c++ code on the platform, getting the outcome on platform side(let's say Kotlin for instance) and sending it to dart via method channel versus writing the `dart:ffi` interface and directly calling the native c++ code. They basically will provide the same code execution. The only difference I see is that the MethodChannel call would be an async task vs `dart:ffi` which will be synchronous. Apart from the async behavior, will there be any difference(performance primarily) in getting the response from either of the technique.

Comment: Presumably it would be easier to code one ffi interface than all of Dart to swift and kotlin and thence to C through uni or whatever. Callbacks are a little easier with method channel over ffi. Presumably the ffi interface is more performant than serialising over a channel, but will it be significant?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a tour repo for dart:ffi: https://github.com/Sunbreak/native_interop.tour

1. Async/Sync

- For MethodChannel, both `Dart -> Native` and `Native -> Dart` are asynchronous
- For dart:ffi, `Dart -> Native` and `Native -> Dart` could be synchronous (except native call from non-mutator thread of Isolate)

2. Memory

- For MethodChannel, each interop requires serilization/deseriliazation
- For dart:ffi, you'd easily write C-like memory-efficient operation

3. Performance

dart:ffi synchronous interop has a good advantage on non-frequent small data

https://www.xdea.xyz/2020/11/flutter-platform-channel-%e6%80%a7%e8%83%bd%e6%b5%8b%e8%af%95/

Comment: Does this mean that Method Channels are generally slower? What if I am trying to build an Engine that utilizes the device sensors, the GPU for rendering and inference, and also send requests to the cloud all in real time? Would a Method Channel be too much and ffi be faster? (with memory considerations)